# Laravel 5.8 Redirecting after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In my Laravel application there is the default login page aswell as a login form inside a dropdown. As I have it set up now, after a successfull login a user is redirected to the index page, however, If a user uses the login form in the dropdown I want him to stay on the page he is already.

Is there a better practice than adding a seperate method for logging in via the dropdown?

Comment: can you explain bit more. I think you know about `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: I did use `php artisan make:auth` and on the default login page, after successfully logging in the user gets redirected to the /index. However theres also a login form within the nav bar and after logging in from there a user also gets redirected to /index, but I want him to stay on this page.

Comment: sorry still your question is not clear. Are you expecting to user to be at same page even after successfully logged in

Comment: Yes I want them to get more or less redirected to the page they were on at the moment they hit the login button

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axios` or `ajax` to login and stay on the page.

Example for `axios`, in your script write something like this

```
$("body").on("submit", "#login-form", function (e) {
    var action = $(this).attr("action"); // your login url

    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post(action, $(this).serialize())
     .then(function (response) {
        // do something from the response
        // i.e. display error or update navbar to logged in view
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error here
     });
});
```

Example for `ajax`, in your script write something like this

```
$("#login-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // show loading or whatever
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // do something from the response
            // i.e. display error or update navbar to logged in view
        },
        error: function(xhr) { // if error occured            
            var status = xhr.statusText;
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            // handle error here                       
        }
    });
});
```

In both examples, I assume that you will have a login form with an ID `login-form`